# Prodcts are delivered from other warehouse

Tags: odoo-10

I have to received sale order in own warehouse, but it delivered product from different warehouse it is possible or possible so how i can ? 
I have defined example here :
 Sale order is from : Warehouse X
and its product is delivered from Warehouse Y 
and its another product is delivered from Warehouse Z.
Is that possible ?

In this question warehouse x is only inform to warehouse y and z and then y and z warehouse is delivered product directly customer and invoice is create in our warehouse x.

and that is posible then how i can set which type of configuration in odoov10 enterprise edition module.
anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible using the **routes**.

checked for go to inventory app in **configuration ->** routes menu in select **routes** and create new routes.
when routes is create in this add **procurements rule** in select source location select other warehouse which is delivered product.

then go to **inventory control** menu and select **product** in this select existing product or create new product and go to in the **inventory** tab and select you own routes in this product,
then second product select another routes.

then create new sale order and add product in this added above product which in select our own route then do confirm sale order,

above right side corner display delivery of both products are different warehouses.